# Update View on button click SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

noob here
I am creating a game in which you have to flip tiles and find pairs.
Now I am faced with the following problem: when I click on the "New Game" button, I need the tiles to be updated and filled with a new array, but this does not happen.
My assumption is that after clicking the button I need to update the view, but I could not figure out how to do this.
Help me please

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    var model: MemoryGameTheme
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 75))]) {
                    ForEach (viewModel.cards) { card in
                        CardView(card: card)
                            .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                viewModel.choose(card)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                newGame
                Spacer()
                nameTheme
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    var newGame: some View {
                Button(action: {
                    model.refreshTheme()
                    self.onActivate()
                }, label: {
                    Text("New Game")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                })
    }
    var nameTheme: some View {
        Text ("\(MemoryGameTheme.themeName)")
            .font(.title3)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
    }
}



struct CardView: View {
    let card: MemoryGame<String>.Card
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if card.isFaceUp {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(card.content).font(.largeTitle)
            } else if card.isMatched {
                shape.opacity(0)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let game = EmojiMemoryGame()
        let theme = MemoryGameTheme()
        ContentView(viewModel: game, model: theme)
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        ContentView(viewModel: game, model: theme)
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Accessibility
import SwiftUI

class MemoryGameTheme: ObservableObject {
    
    enum ChoiseTheme: CaseIterable {
        case car
        case animal
        case item
        case food
        case face
    }
    
    static var choiseTheme = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍❄️", "", "", ""]
    static var themeName = "Animals"
    static var colorCard = Color.gray
    
    func theme(_ choiseTheme: ChoiseTheme) {
        let randomTheme = ChoiseTheme.allCases.randomElement()!
        switch randomTheme {
        case .car:
            let emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✈️", "", "", "", "", "⛵️", ""] // red
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme = emojis
            MemoryGameTheme.themeName = "Cars"
            MemoryGameTheme.colorCard = .red
        case .animal:
            let emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍❄️", "", "", ""]
            // gray
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme = emojis
            MemoryGameTheme.themeName = "Animals"
            MemoryGameTheme.colorCard = .gray
        case .item:
            let emojis = ["", "⌚️", "", "⌨️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☎️", "", "⏰", "", "", "", ""]
            // purple
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme = emojis
            MemoryGameTheme.themeName = "Items"
            MemoryGameTheme.colorCard = .purple
        case .food:
            let emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
            // yelow
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme = emojis
            MemoryGameTheme.themeName = "Food"
            MemoryGameTheme.colorCard = .yellow
        case .face:
            let emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", ""] // green
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme = emojis
            MemoryGameTheme.themeName = "Face"
            MemoryGameTheme.colorCard = .green
        }
        print(randomTheme)
        print(MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme)
    }
    
    func refreshTheme() {
        theme(ChoiseTheme.car)   
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

class EmojiMemoryGame: ObservableObject {
    
    static func createMemoreGame() -> MemoryGame<String> {
        return MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairOfCards: MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme.count) { pairIndex in
            MemoryGameTheme.choiseTheme[pairIndex]
        }
    }
    
    @Published private var model: MemoryGame<String> = createMemoreGame()
    
    var cards: Array<MemoryGame<String>.Card> {
        model.cards
    }
    
    // MARK: - Intens(s)
    
    func choose(_ card: MemoryGame<String>.Card) {
        model.choose(card)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct MemoryGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable {
    
    private(set) var cards: Array<Card>
    
    private var indexOfTheOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard: Int?
    
    mutating func choose(_ card: Card) {
        if  let chosenIndex = cards.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }),
            !cards[chosenIndex].isFaceUp,
            !cards[chosenIndex].isMatched {
            if let potentialMatchIndex = indexOfTheOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard {
                if cards[chosenIndex].content == cards[potentialMatchIndex].content {
                    cards[chosenIndex].isMatched = true
                    cards[potentialMatchIndex].isMatched = true
                }
                indexOfTheOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard = nil
            } else {
                for index in cards.indices {
                    cards[index].isFaceUp = false
                }
                indexOfTheOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard = chosenIndex
            }
            
            cards[chosenIndex].isFaceUp.toggle()
        }
        //        print("\(cards)")
    }
    
    init (numberOfPairOfCards: Int, createCardContent: (Int) -> CardContent) {
        cards = Array<Card>()
        // add numberOfPairOfCards x2 cards to cards array
        for pairIndex in 0..<numberOfPairOfCards {
            let content = createCardContent(pairIndex)
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2))
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2+1))
        }
        cards.shuffle()
    }
    
    struct Card: Identifiable  {
        var isFaceUp: Bool = false
        var isMatched: Bool = false
        var content: CardContent
        var id: Int
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model is not declared as  StateObject, so any change in it will not be reflected in the UI.

EDIT : there is a logic problem in your code :

- model is not used as a var but as a link to static class properties
- the theme is choosen via static properties from MemoryGameClass

As you use static properties of a class, the values are only used when something that use this properties is updated, not when the property is updated.

The theme should be a published var of EmojisMemoryGame and declared as a struct. So when something changes in properties of the theme, it will cause a redraw of the view.

Edit 2 : what I meant :
Theme as a struct :

```
struct MemoryGameTheme {
    // List of themes
    static let allThemes: [ChoiseTheme: MemoryGameTheme] =
    [.car: MemoryGameTheme(choiseTheme: .car, themeEmojis: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✈️", "", "", "", "", "⛵️", ""], themeName: "Cars", colorCard: .red),
     .animal: MemoryGameTheme(choiseTheme: .animal, themeEmojis: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍❄️", "", "", ""], themeName: "Animals", colorCard: .gray),
     .item: MemoryGameTheme(choiseTheme: .item, themeEmojis: ["", "⌚️", "", "⌨️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☎️", "", "⏰", "", "", "", ""], themeName: "Items", colorCard: .purple),
     .food: MemoryGameTheme(choiseTheme: .food, themeEmojis: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], themeName: "Food", colorCard: .yellow),
     .face: MemoryGameTheme(choiseTheme: .face, themeEmojis: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", ""], themeName: "Face", colorCard: .green)]
    
    // Type of themes
    enum ChoiseTheme: CaseIterable {
        case car
        case animal
        case item
        case food
        case face
    }
    var choiseTheme: ChoiseTheme = .animal
    var themeEmojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍❄️", "", "", ""]
    var themeName = "Animals"
    var colorCard = Color.gray
    
    mutating func changeTheme(_ choiseTheme: ChoiseTheme) {
        let randomTheme = ChoiseTheme.allCases.randomElement()!
        // Initialise the theme from static dictionnary
        let theme = Self.allThemes[randomTheme]!
        self.choiseTheme = theme.choiseTheme
        self.themeEmojis = theme.themeEmojis
        self.themeName = theme.themeName
        self.colorCard = theme.colorCard

        print(randomTheme)
        print(choiseTheme)
    }
    
    // Mutating func to change theme
    mutating func refreshTheme() {
        changeTheme(ChoiseTheme.car)
    }
}
```

EmojiGame including theme as Published var :

```
class EmojiMemoryGame: ObservableObject {
    // Create a new memory game based on specific theme
    static func createMemoreGame(theme: MemoryGameTheme) -> MemoryGame<String> {
        return MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairOfCards: theme.themeEmojis.count) { pairIndex in
            theme.themeEmojis[pairIndex]
        }
    }
    
    // This model is a struct
    @Published private var model: MemoryGame<String> = EmojiMemoryGame.createMemoreGame(theme: MemoryGameTheme())
    // This is the theme of the model
    @Published private var theme: MemoryGameTheme = MemoryGameTheme()
    
    // To acces model and theme comtents
    var themeName: String {
        theme.themeName
    }
    var colorCard: Color {
        theme.colorCard
    }

    var cards: Array<MemoryGame<String>.Card> {
        model.cards
    }
    
    // MARK: - Intens(s)
    func choose(_ card: MemoryGame<String>.Card) {
        model.choose(card)
    }
    
    // When refreshing theme, create a new game with teh new theme
    func refreshTheme() {
        theme.refreshTheme()
        model = Self.createMemoreGame(theme: theme)
    }
}
```

The Content view using ObservedObject Emoji game :

```
struct ContentView: View {
// emoji memory game must declared as Observed object
// to enable SwiftUI to update when something change in it
@ObservedObject var emojisGame: EmojiMemoryGame
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 75))]) {
                ForEach (emojisGame.cards) { card in
                    CardView(card: card)
                        .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            emojisGame.choose(card)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        // Use theme color for cards
        .foregroundColor(emojisGame.colorCard)
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            newGame
            Spacer()
            nameTheme
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
}

var newGame: some View {
    Button(action: {
        // Reset emoji game with theme change
        emojisGame.refreshTheme()
        self.onActivate()
    }, label: {
        Text("New Game")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
    })
}
var nameTheme: some View {
    Text ("\(emojisGame.themeName)")
        .font(.title3)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
}

func onActivate() {
    
}
```

}

Comment: hello, can you please write in more detail what you mean?
I don't understand
I do "@StateObject var model: MemoryGameTheme", but this dont help

Comment: Updated my answer : some logic error in the way you added the them make its changes not taken into account when you want.